# Spring MVC redirection issue on tomcat 7 running on Debian

Tags: java, spring-mvc, debian, tomcat7

I am a newbie to Spring MVC. I am using version 4.1.6 within a webapp. This webapp is running on a Tomcat 7 server. When I run it on windows, everything is just 
allright. However, on Debian a redirection problem occurs:

1. I go to my index page : domain.com/appName
2. Click on a button that makes a POST request
3. Get redirected to "domain.com/appName/search" on Windows. But get redirected to
   "domain.com/search" on Debian (which makes a 404 error).

Here are my sources:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app    id="app"
        version="3.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>appName</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**appName-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ghayth.vtc" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

**SearchController.java**

```
package com.ghayth.vtc.controller;
...
@Controller
public class SearchController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(HttpSession httpSession, Model model) {
...
    return "index";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String search(...) {
...
    return "search";
}
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
...
<form:form role="form" method="post" modelAttribute="searchForm" action="search">
...
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form:form>
```

All my JSPs are inside "/WEB-INF/jsp".

Is there something wrong? And is there a specific configuration for tomcat 7 on Debian that must be done?

Thanks!!